# How to set values on scrollbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to set values scrollbox. But i don't know how to set.

```js
var str = "Rose, Tim, Tom";
var words = str.split(', ');
var i;
for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  $('#nameList').val(words[i])
}
```

```css
.vertical-menu {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: #b8d1f3;
}

.vertical-menu a.active {
  background-color: #1C84C6;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vertical-menu">
  <a href="#" class="active">List</a>
  <a href="#" id="nameList" name="nameList"></a>
</div>
```

I want:
image scrollbox kkk

- List
- Rose
- Tim
- Tom

Comment: `val()` is getting/setting the values of inputs. If you are trying to set the text of `<a>`, use `text()` or `html()`. Or `append()` if you want to append new text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are trying to build a dropdown, you can use the following:

```js
var str = "Rose, Tim, Tom";

const optionsEl = document.querySelector('#options');
str
  .split(',')
  .reduce((node, name) => {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    const anchor = document.createElement('a');
    anchor.setAttribute('href', '#');
    anchor.innerText = name.trim();
    li.appendChild(anchor);
    node.appendChild(li);
  
    return node;
  }, optionsEl)
```

```css
.vertical-menu {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: #b8d1f3;
}

.vertical-menu a.active {
  background-color: #1C84C6;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical-menu">
    <a href="#" class="active">List</a>
    <ul id="options">
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Eddie mentioned, you should use the append() method as you are overwriting the content in the nameList div each time you iterate through your loop. You could also format the element in a manner to make sure the elements are stacked as they are appeneded:

```
var str = "Rose, Tim, Tom";
var words = str.split(', ');
var i;
for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  //create placeholder var to format how element should be - this will create a
  //p tag with the content within. This li_element is then appended.
  let li_element = $(["<p>", words[i],"</p>"].join("\n"));
  $('#nameList').append(li_element)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to append more a tags to the parent vertical menu if you want to add more entries.  You also need to use `<br>` tags to force the new lines unless you change your css to style them vertically. Something like this will append the items to the parent `.vertical-menu`

```js
var str = "Rose, Tim, Tom";
var words = str.split(', ');
var i;
for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  $('.vertical-menu').append(`<br><a href="#">${words[i]}</a>`);
}
```

```css
.vertical-menu {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: #b8d1f3;
}

.vertical-menu a.active {
  background-color: #1C84C6;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vertical-menu">
  <a href="#" class="active">List</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = function() {
var str = "Rose, Tim, Tom";
var words = str.split(', ');
var listStr = '<li><a href="#" id="%id%" name="%name%">%data%</a></li>';
var i;
for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  $('#list-items').append(listStr.replace('%id%', words[i]).replace('%name%', words[i]).replace('%data%', words[i]));
}
}
```

```css
.vertical-menu {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: #b8d1f3;
}

.vertical-menu a.active {
  background-color: #1C84C6;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vertical-menu" id="list-items">
  <a href="#" class="active">List</a>
</div>
```